# how to merge elments based on a condition in xelemnt?

Tags: c#, linq

I have sample xelement:

```
<Books>
  <Book>
    <Id>123</Id>
    <EndDate>01/11/2009</EndDate>
    <Price>$0.00</Price>
    <tag1>0</tag1>
    <tag2>0</tag2>
   </Book>
   <Book>
    <Id>567</Id>
    <EndDate>01/01/2001</EndDate>
    <Price>$0.00</Price>
    <tag1>1</tag1>
     <tag2>2</tag2>
   </Book>
   <Book>
    <Id>567</Id>
    <EndDate>01/01/2001</EndDate>
     <tag1>22</tag1>
     <tag2>33</tag2>
    <Price>$0.00</Price>
    </Book>
</Books>
```

I have to  merge 2 nodes  ( with coma seperated) when enddates are same .  for the above input i shoud get fallowing out put .

```
<Books>
  <Book>
    <Id>123</Id>
    <EndDate>01/11/2009</EndDate>
    <Price>$0.00</Price>
    <tag1>0</tag1>
    <tag2>0</tag2>
   </Book>
   <Book>
    <Id>567</Id>
    <EndDate>01/01/2001</EndDate>
    <Price>$0.00</Price>
    <tag1>1,22</tag1>
     <tag2>2,33</tag2>
   </Book>
  </Books>
```

I tried using aggregate function but I  am not able to add end date condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

google  XML Serialization in C#.

1. Deserialize the xml file to List as example.
2. Do your logic "remove some record or create new merged list"
3. Serialize the new list to xml file

or

> ```
> public class Book
> {
>   public int Id { get; set; }
>   public Decimal Price { get; set; }
>   public DateTime EndDate{ get; set; }
>   public string tag1{ get; set; }
>   public string tag1{ get; set; }
> }
> ....
>
> XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("Books.xml");
> List<Book> BookList1=
>   (from Book in xmlDoc.Descendants("Book")
>    select new Tutorial
>    {
>      Id = tutorial.Element("Id").Value,
>      Price = tutorial.Element("Price").Value,
>      EndDate = DateTime.Parse(tutorial.Element("EndDate").Value),
>      tag1= tutorial.Element("tag1").Value,
>      tag2= tutorial.Element("tag2").Value
>    }).ToList<Tutorial>();
> ....
> var BookGroups = from g in  BookList1 group g by Id into g
> select new{Key=g.Key,Books=g};
>
> List<Book> BookList2= new List<Book>();
> foreach(var g in BookGroups)
> { 
>   Book book = new Book();
>   book.Id=g.Key;
>   foreach(var b in g.Books)
>   {
> // put your logic 
>   if(b.Price > book.Price) book.Price =b.Price;
>   if(b.EndDate > book.EndDate) book.EndDate =b.EndDate;
>   book.tag1+=b.tag1+",";
>   book.tag2+=b.tag2+",";
>  }
>  book.tag1= book.tag1.Trim(',');
>  book.tag2= book.tag2.Trim(',');
>  BookList2.add(book);
> }
> ```

Comment: Yes thats what i was doing right now but can it be done using Linq  functions like grigate or concat?

Comment: yes you can do it with linq by using Group By, then loop throw each group and do concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the following lines may get you started (illustrative - not production quality):

```
// XElement sourceElement contains the original "Books" element.

var matchingBookGroups = 
    from x in sourceElement.Elements("Book")
    group x by string.Format("{0}-{1}", x.Element("Id").Value, x.Element("EndDate").Value) into g
    select new { Key = g.Key, Values = g };

XElement result =
    new XElement("Books",
        from matchingBookElements in matchingBookGroups
        let firstMatchingBookElement = matchingBookElements.Values.First()
        select
            new XElement("Book",
                firstMatchingBookElement.Element("Id"),
                firstMatchingBookElement.Element("EndDate"),
                firstMatchingBookElement.Element("Price"),
                    new XElement("tag1", string.Join(",", matchingBookElements.Values.Elements("tag1").Select(x => x.Value).ToArray())),
                    new XElement("tag2", string.Join(",", matchingBookElements.Values.Elements("tag2").Select(x => x.Value).ToArray()))));
```

Comment: thx for this i will take this idea but isnt it  like we are doing 2 loops 1 for gruping and then loop2 for  merging  . my idea is while groupingitself can we add an agrigate  ?

Comment: var kk =  servicestags.Elements("ServiceTag").Select(T =>
                       {
                           var values = T.Elements().Aggregate( (a1,a2)=> {a1.Element("enddate") == a2.Element("enddate") return new XElement("book", "enddate"+"newdate")})
                           }